# Delete Responses - Resume forms

Tags: google-apps-script

Is possible create a script to delete answers **Summary summary of responses** ?

Is possible create a script to delete answers **Summary answers**?

Answer (score 0):

To delete the summary of responses if the script is bound to the form the code is:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
form.deleteAllResponses();
```

If the script is bound to the sheet then the code is:

```
FormApp.openByUrl(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl()).deleteAllResponses();
```

Keep in mind that these pieces of code will only delete the responses stored in the [form's response store](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteAllResponses()). If the responses are stored in a spreadshet as well it will not delete them there.

I'm not sure what you mean by "Summary answers". If you were talking about deleting the responses in the spreadsheet this does not seem to be possible. When I try to do that I get this error:
"Cannot delete row with form questions. Consider hiding the row instead."